# cannot pass data from php script to angularjs using angularjs php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

when ever i tried to update form response from php script shows undefined.
**script.js**

```
$scope.Edit = function() {
  $http.post("update.php", {
    'id' : $scope.id,
       'Name': $scope.Name
    })
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.names = response.data;
        console.log(response.data.success);
     }, function(){
        console.log(response.data.fail);
     })
 }
```

**update.php**

```
<?php
    try {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=angularjs", "root", "");
        $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $response = array();
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
        $Sql = "UPDATE register SET Name = :Name WHERE id = :id";
        $stmt = $link->prepare($Sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":Name", $json['Name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $json['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $response['success'] = "successfully inserted"; 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $response['fail'] = "Error.".$e;
    }
?>
```

**template.html**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="welcomeController">
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
    <p>{{ success }}</p>
    <p>{{ fail }}</p>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover table-borderless">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>DOB</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="users in names">
                <tr>
                    <form>
                        <td><input type="text" ng-model="users.id" readonly></td>
                        <td><input type="text" ng-model="users.Name"></td>
                        <td>{{ users.Email }}</td>
                        <td>{{ users.DOB }}</td>
                        <td><button type="submit" ng-click="Edit()" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button></td>
                        <td><button type="submit" ng-click="Delete()" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

i need response from php script as updated successfully but it shows undefined. i tried to debug many times i cannot see what mistake i have done.

Comment: What exactly is showing undefined? Is it update.php or script.php? Did you inspect the xhr in the browser's developer tools? Are you sure your `$http.post` code is sending JSON? Because you might want to check `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST['Name']` instead in your PHP script.

Comment: Your PHP script isn't returning anything, try `finally { echo $response; }`.

Comment: @JuanEizmendi thanks, now i can receive response but the problem is it shows updated but the database is not updated.

Comment: try dumping `$json` to see if you're getting the value, or try as @ChrisG mention `$_POST` style

Comment: @JuanEizmendi i tred using json it shows updated but database is not updated and using post it shows undefined and in php script it shows trying to access array offset of type null

Comment: so, it probably isn't been sent by the front end, you can see what it's been sent in the networking of the dev tools

Comment: it does not shows any errors but the database is not updated. i think that there is error in php and it does not shows.